# How to set the latest version number when distributing python package at pypi?

Tags: python, pip, pypi

I have uploaded my own package(https://pypi.python.org/pypi/combine2xlsx) to `Pypi`, and the latest version is `0.1.9`.

However, when I try to search it via `pip3 search combine2xlsx`, it shows:

> combine2xlsx   - Combine multi excel files into one large xlsx
>
> INSTALLED: 0.1.6
>
> LATEST:    0.0.1

Why is the latest version `0.0.1`?  Similarly, if I search it the search box at https://pypi.python.org/, it also goes to https://pypi.python.org/pypi/combine2xlsx/0.0.1 by default.

How to set the latest version number?